# Object returns `false` for both `true` and `false` with the equality operator

Tags: javascript

Why does an object return `false` for both `true` and `false` with the equality operator, but `true` when no operator is used?

```
var test = {
    one: "1",
    two: "2"
};

if (test) console.log("if"); // true
if (test == true) console.log("true"); // false
if (test == false) console.log("false"); // false
```

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5D/)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `==`, there are rules of type conversion.

- If one of the operands is Boolean, the Boolean operand is converted
  to 1 if it is true and 0 if it is false.
- If an object is compared with a number or string, JavaScript attempts
  to return the default value for the object. Operators attempt to
  convert the object to a primitive value, a String or Number value,
  using the valueOf and toString methods of the objects. If this
  attempt to convert the object fails, a runtime error is generated.

So `true` and `false` is converted to `1` and `0`.

`test.toString()` returns string `"[object Object]"` which is not equal to `0` nor `1`.

Comment: `console.log({} == "[object Object]"); // true` That makes sense now :)

Answer (score 4):

`if(test)` returns true because this condition will return true if `test` object is defined/exists. if `test` is  `undefined` or `NAN` or `null` or `false` or `""` it will return false.

And rest of the comparisons are self explanatory as this is

```
if (test == true)
```

will return false as `test` is not a bool values which can be compare with `true`. Instead of this you can try this comparison

```
if (test["one"] == "1") 
  console.log("true")
```

**[Js FIddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wnp5D/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
if (test) console.log("if");
```

returns true because it is checking if object exists/defined.

```
if (test == true) console.log("true"); // false
if (test == false) console.log("false"); // false
```

returns false because test is not a **Boolean** so it cannot be compare to true or false. So it will be always **false**.